# Including bootstrap css is effecting D3 mousemove event data

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, d3.js

I've been trying to put together a project skeleton to use Angular-UI (bootstrap integration) with D3.

I've been putting together snippets from SO questions, tutorials etc. and when I put together something that is simply supposed to display the coordinates of the mouse when it is moved over svg element, something really weird happened. The mouse over code that worked just as expected began to use decimal point for only X coordinate.

I've managed to put together a js fiddle that demonstrates that the bootstrap css is the source of the behaviour.

To make things even more complicated, if the width value I'm using in a css class has a value that is slightly larger then the behaviour goes away.

To see the problem take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A3fcH/):

Simply run the fiddle and move the mouse around the circles. You'll see that only X coordinate has the decimal point and lots of digits to the right of it.

Now change the width from 1172px to 1200px in the container-non-responsive class in the style sheet, giving you:

```
.container-non-responsive {
                /* Margin/padding copied from Bootstrap */
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
                padding-left: 15px;
                padding-right: 15px;

                /* Set width to your desired site width */
                width:1200px;
                height: 100%;
            }
```

Now run again and move the mouse. No decimal point. If I print the position to console, I can see that the position object indeed has X coordinate with the decimal. So this is d3 returning an X coordinate with decimal point when bootstrap css is included and when I use the custom width with some values (600px works OK too)

I have absolutely no idea about how to track this one down.

Comment: Actually I don't what you wanted to do with the X and Y co-ordinates. What are you up to do with X and Y co-ordinates?

Comment: That does not matter. The question is why the css and coordinate values are leading to this behaviour?

Comment: You could have a look at the D3 source code to see how the positions are computed, but I'm not convinced that this is an issue in practice as we're talking about a fraction of a pixel here.